# Official Nvidia drivers not compatible with ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics, bumblebee

So i'm sort of at a loss for words here, I have a brand new gaming laptop with a Nvidia Geoforce GTX 860M gpu. I noticed that the computer wasn't recognizing it.

If I "optirun" anything I get the error:

[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

So I went to the nvidia website and downloaded the listed compatible driver. I ran the installer and it removed all gui from my computer. I was only able to load the terminal. I tried messing around with the config files but I ended up just reformatting and reinstalling ubuntu.

I don't think the nvidia drivers are compatibile with ubuntu so now I'm not sure what to do, how can I get the drivers I need? Seems like a bit of waste to use my integrated gpu if I have a powerful nvidia one on the machine.

Comment: The driver from the Nvidia web site is a clsed source driver, if it does not work file a bug report with Nvidia - http://www.nvidia.com/page/support.html and https://devtalk.nvidia.com/

Answer (score 2):

That's why you're supposed to use the driver which are distrubuted through Ubuntu repositories. When you download driver from Nvidia site, it will modify kernel.

The way you are supposed to get to the nvidia drivers (though not newest) is to open `Software & Updates` from your Ubuntu Dash, click on the `Additional Drivers` tab and pick the driver from the menu which you want. Chances are that the nuveau driver is already installed, but if you want the proprietary nvidia driver, choose it, click on `Apply Changes` and after and wait for a while.

A alternative way to install these these same drivers  - Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

For the tested version, or for the bleeding edge version (possible bugs)

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction for finding the correct driver?

Comment: You can open `Software & Updates` program from Ubuntu Dash and then click on the `Additional Drivers` tab. You will be provided with several versions of drivers for you nvidia card, I suspect that the standard nuveau driver will be installed since it's free. If you'd like the official nvidia driver, just select it, then Apply settings and after a while, you;re good to go.

Comment: Would you please update your answer with those instructions.

Comment: The Additional Drivers does not show any available drivers, not sure why.

Comment: Try run `lspci | grep -i nvidia` in terminal console and tell us your output - if it does not show anything, Linux does not detect your nvidia card at all.

Comment: Do you have an optimus GPU ? This needs a different driver than a dedicated card

Comment: Well I do have Optimus on my laptop and I am using the drivrs provided by Ubuntu. Optimus or not, the card itself should be at least detected.

Comment: Beware the additional drivers takes some time to show!
I'm using an Nvidia driver, but Software & Updates takes a couble of minutes to even contemplate that there are proprietary drivers in use, so be patient specially on this Tab!

Comment: @A.Kounovský If you have optimus you should install Bumblebee to take advantage of the hybrid GPU's provided in the laptop.

Comment: The `powertop` I use for better battery life works with my dedicated card just fine using `bbswitch` or something similar, and when I play I get better performance than with `bumblebee`. Thanks for caring, though.